# Tracking link in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, analytics, adobe-analytics

I use adobe analytics and try to track links using this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() { 
    s.tl(this, 'e', 'link', null, 'navigate'); 
    return false; 
});
```

or

```
$("a").click(function() { 
    s.tl(this, 'e', 'link', null, 'navigate'); 
    return false; 
});
```

and when I tested it and click in a link in Chrome I receive for the first the status page canceled and using the second option in chrome everything works fine but in Firefox I receive `status 0 GET (NS_BINDING_ABORTED)`.

Is there any workaround which could run without problem in all browsers or should I fix anything to the previous?

From [here](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/link_manual.html) is the example I use using the second box as example

I found this solution:

```
https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/es/forum/general-topic-forum/custom-link-tracking-capturing-issue
```

Which proposes this as a work around:

```
<script language="javascript">
function pejTracking(linkname,url) {
var s=s_gi('myprodsuite');
s.tl(this,'o',linkname,null,navigate(url));
}
function navigate(url) {
window.location=url;
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="pejTracking('mytest', 'mytestpage.com');return false;">This really works!</a>
```

Is it possible to make it to work with the JQuery document or a onclick function as I have at the start of my post and there is any need to have the onclick in every link?

Comment: Why are you returning `false`?

Comment: Well that will cancel the event, so if your link was actually going somewhere then it wouldn't with that `return false`

Comment: @mattytommo, the link tracker in Adobe Analytics redirects to the link's href - this is done to make sure the click is tracked before navigating away. So you have to return false, else the default action will take place no matter if the tracking hit has been sent or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is common, and (probably) isn't a problem.

This error occurs because the link tracking image request is designed to let the browser proceed to the next page before waiting for a response from the Adobe data collection servers.

**Adobe Reference:** [NS_Binding_Aborted in Packet Monitors](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/debugger_ns_binding.html)

**Update:**

*You commented:*

> Yes I have seen this but is it possible to fix it?

You are asking to "fix" this as if it's something that is broken.. my point is that it's *not* broken.

But if you insist on wanting to make sure this doesn't show up, you will need to do the solution you already posted in your question.

The jQuery equivalent would be to make use of  [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and then update `window.location` after the `s.tl` call (in `navigate` callback) same as the non-jQuery solution.

*You also asked:*

> And what about chrome?

What about it? This isn't browser-specific. It has to do with timing. Try it enough times in Chrome and you should see that NS_Binding_Aborted error in Chrome, too. Maybe. Depends on connection speed, current CPU resources, internet traffic in general, how the stars are aligned, etc. - you know, all the things that make requests and response happen later rather than sooner.

Comment: Yes I have seen this but is it possible to fix it? And what about chrome?